# Objective C reachability of LAN devices

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, network-programming

I need write a program on Mac OS X to manage some number of projectors on the LAN (using IP address), and I'm trying to figure out how to monitor their connection status. Something like a simple ping just to make sure I can reach them.

I've tried using the NSURLRequest requestWithURL call. It worked, but the program stops responding for quite a while if any of the projectors are offline. I'm just looking to get the status and change the UI indication.

Are there better ways to do this? Any help or point in the right direction would be great, thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the timeoutInterval property on the NSURLRequest.  Otherwise you'll have to run the ping connection in a background thread, or else use use NSURLConnect and check the asynchronous callbacks delivered to the delegate.

Comment: Thank you. NSURLConnect and asynchronous callbacks to a delegate works. Curious though, how do one run a ping connection through code?

Comment: If you mean a real ping using ICMP ECHO requests, then the normal way to do it is to create a raw socket and craft the ICMP headers yourself.  At least, that's the way we used to do it.