# iPhone - Network Searching

Tags: iphone, networking, network-scan

I am trying to scan a local network for a hardware device. I want my app to have a search feature, but I have no idea how to get started on this. I have used Reachability before, but can't see how that will help in this situation. What do I need to do to scan/search a network?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374564/objective-c-reachability-of-lan-devices

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055000/get-list-of-devices-on-lan-in-c, You can call c-functions from objective-c, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339843/calling-c-function-in-objective-c-awake-from-nib

Comment: Ok great, thanks for pointing me in this direction